# jump from ajax result back to spring boot

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-boot

I have the following problem. I get results from an ajax call from my spring boot controller . I show them in a jquery-accordion (our customer wants that). now the user should come back to spring after clicking on a link with the id. How do I do that?

successful ajax

```
$.ajax({
                url: $("#suche").attr( "action"),
                data: JSON.stringify(json),
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,

                beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                },
                success: function(daten) {
                    var respContent = "";

                    for (i = 0; i < daten.length; i++)
                    {
                        var tmp = daten[i];
                        respContent += "<h3>"+tmp.kdCode + "</h3>";
                        respContent += "<div>";
                        respContent += "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"id\" value=\""+tmp.kd_id+"\">";
                        respContent += "<p><a href=\"#\">"+tmp.kd_strasse+", "+ tmp.kd_plz + " " + tmp.kd_ort +"</a></p>";
                        respContent += "</div>";
                    }

                    $("#ergebnisse").html(respContent);
                    $( "#ergebnisse" ).accordion({
                        heightStyle: "content"
                    });
                }
            });
```

the div

```
 <!-- Ausgeben der Ergebnisse und Rücksprung zu Spring -->
                        <form:form id="ergs" action="localhost:8080/address/detailansicht" cssClass="form-horizontal" method="post" modelAttribute="AdressVO">
                            <div id="ergebnisse" >


                            </div>
                        </form:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was very simple.
Inside the returned data's, i added a

```
<a href = '#' onclick='detailDatas("+tmp.kd_id+")'</a>
```

In the detailDatas-Function is an ajax to the springcontroller

Additionally we have a
      var adresse = "/address/detailansicht1?street='";
.
.
.

and  all the returned datas
.
And in the controller we give back the new jsp - and voila it works.
Maybe not the best solution but a working solution.